# React Native ScrollView snapping back to top after release

Tags: scrollview, react-native

I have used ScrollView in other apps adding just a `style={styles.container}` with the styles. However in this app I am creating in my styles I have `alignItems:'flex-start'` which throws an error with just `style={styles.container}` and instead you need to pass in `alignItems:'flex-start'` through `contentContainerStyle={styles.container}`.

Error: `Invariant Violation: ScrollView child layout (["alignItems"]) must by applied through the contentContainerStyle prop.`

However when I add `contentContainerStyle` when scrolling down in the view, once the finger is lifted off the phone (or release of the mouse in simulator), the scroll automatically goes back to the top. If I just use `style={styles.container}` and take out the `alignItems:'flex-start'` it scrolls correctly, but my items in the UI are not laid out how I need them. What is causing it to scroll back to the top with `contentContainerStyle` and is there a fix?

render:

```
var _that = this;
var iconsToShow = icons.map(function (icon, i){
  if(i < 81){
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => _that.changeIcon(indexToChange, icon)}
        underlayColor='#F7F7F7'
        key={i}>
          <Text style={styles.iconText}><IonIcons name={icon} size={30} color="#555" /></Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
});

return (
  <Carousel width={SCREEN_WIDTH} animate={false} indicatorColor="#444" inactiveIndicatorColor="#999" indicatorAtBottom={false} indicatorOffset={16}>
    <View>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>{iconsToShow}</ScrollView>
    </View>

    <View>
      //next page for carousel
    </View>

  </Carousel>
);
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I figured out how to get it to scroll. Instead of having the `View` wrapping the `ScrollView` and the `ScrollView` having any flex styling or `alignItems:'flex-start'` with `contentContainerStyle={styles.container}`, put that on the `View` which is a child of the `ScrollView` and just use `style=` instead of `contentContainerStyle=`.

render:

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.goalName}>{goal}</Text>
    <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
        {iconsToShow}
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Styling:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        paddingLeft:20,
        paddingRight:20
    },
    viewContainer:{
        flexDirection:'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        flex: 1
    },
    iconText:{
        paddingLeft:15,
        paddingRight:15,
        paddingTop:15,
        paddingBottom:15
    },
    goalName:{
        textAlign:'center',
        marginTop:40,
        marginBottom:10,
        fontSize:20
    }
});
```

Comment: You should select this as the answer since it fixed your problem. Also, this was the same problem I had using a FlatList, probably because it subclasses ScrollView.

Comment: Hi Doug, were you able to fix the issue. I am having the same issue with flatlist and could not find the solution

Answer (score 2):

If someone still couldn't fix the problem, try put {flex: 1} into "all" parents of the ScrollView